# Ubuntu styled notifications in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, notifications

I recently installed Linux Mint 15 with Cinnamon. It ran smoothly after forcing a kernel update by activating visibility of "Level 5" "dangerous packages". Later, after a post-update reboot, my notifications look like those seen in Ubuntu's Unity (Notify OSD). I have only installed things through Mint's software center or apt-get.

It doesn't seem like the notifications stack up in the taskbar applet either. I do get the ubuntu styled notifications by triggering them with notify-send. The ubuntu styled notifications also replaces the volume up/down as well as brightness up/down notifications.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some package must have installed notify-osd. Uninstalling it fixed my issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove notify-osd
```

I also made a bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1196502)